# is this the right way to display 3 array elements each time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, product

is this the right way to display 3 array elements each time? please see the demo below

**NOTE:**  Change array items either add or remove array values or even you can change itemsperow=4 to see the changes

**javascript**

```
 var index=0;
    var arr=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i',10];
     var tot =arr.length;
     var itemsperow=3;
      var loop=Math.round(tot/itemsperow);
      //checking if remainder exist 
      if(tot%itemsperow!=0){
        loop=loop+1;
      }

     for(i=1;i<=loop;i++)
        {
            console.log("<div>");
            for(j=1;j<=itemsperow;++j){
                if(index==tot){
                    break;
                }
              console.log('<span>'+arr[index]+'</span>');

              ++index;
              }

            console.log("</div>");

            if(index==tot){
                    break;
                }
        }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/87rxL785/

Comment: your question doesn't explain clearly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Please make your question clear. It does not make sense at all.

Comment: i have posted example please check it and rate it

Comment: This question should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ We don't review code here.

Answer (score 1):

Use modulus to detect when you've output each 3 items:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if ((i % itemsperrow) == 0) {
        if (i != 0) { // Close last DIV
            console.log('</div>');
        }
        console.log('<div>');
    }
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
if (i > 0) {
    console.log('</div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what you want to do i think

```
var arr=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i',10];
        for(i=0;i<arr.length;){
          console.log('<div>');
          for(j=0;i<arr.length && j<3;++i,++j){
            console.log('<p>'+arr[i]+'</p>');
          }
          console.log('</div>');
        }
```